# What does "the conditional distribution given a stochastic process" mean?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, definition, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space.

Let $X,Y$ be random variables on $\Omega$.

Then, we say $Z\sim X|Y$ iff (i) $\int_{Y^{-1}(A)} X dP = \int_{Y^{-1}(A)} Z dP$ and (ii) $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Now,  let $S:\mathscr{\mathbb{R}} \times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a stochastic process.

What does it mean by $X|S$?

There are numerous papers saying like "... because $X|S \sim S$, $P(X\in A|S)= S(A)...$.

I think this is NOT actually a conditional expectation, but it is just a way to denote De Finneti theorem. Isn't it?

Note that $S$ can be seen as a measurable map $\Omega\rightarrow \prod_{A\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \mathbb{R}$. **If the definition $X|S$ is consistent with the standard conditional expectation definition**, $X|S$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, same as $X$. However, since $X|S\sim S$, $X|S$ must take values in  $\prod_{A\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \mathbb{R}$. Do you see inconsistency here?

This makes me confusing, so I am curious what's the definition of $X|S$.

What does $X|S$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

For what you have written as $Z \sim X|Y$ the usual notation is $Z=E(X|Y)$. (I am surprised to see your notation).

We can define $E(X|\mathcal G)$ for any sigma field $\mathcal G$ contained in $\mathcal F$. It is defined as  a random variable $Z$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$ such that $\int_A XdP =\int_A ZdP$ for  every set $A \in \mathcal G$.

Any stochastic process $S$ gives rise to a sigma algebra $\mathcal G$: the smallest one which makes each random variable in the process measurable. This defines $E(X|S)$

Comment: But, as I illustrated in my post, $E(X|S)$ must take values in $X$ according to the standard definition. So it does not make sense to say $E(X|S)=S$.. $X$ is univariate, but $S$ is bivariate.

Comment: I am guessing $X|S\sim S$ means that "$P(X\in A \cap B)= \int_B S(w,A) dP(w)$"..